# try to interpolate data from a csv file, getting error 'x and y arrays must be equal in length along interpolation axis'. found solution doesn't work

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv

I'm completely new to python and data science with it, so please bear with me here. I appreciate every help and try to understand it as much as possible. Following code is what I got so far.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas import read_csv
from matplotlib import pyplot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import interpolate
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
from scipy.interpolate import interp2d

dataset = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\...\csv\Test1K.csv", sep=';', skiprows=0)
x = dataset.iloc[0:1420, 0:1].values
y = dataset.iloc[0:1420, 3:4].values

f = interpolate.interp1d(x, y, kind = 'cubic')
xn =270
t_on = f(xn)
print(t_on)
```

first rows of output from the csv file looks like this:

```
0       [s]     [Celsius]     [Celsius]  [Celsius]   [Celsius]  [Celsius]
1         0        22.747        22.893      0.334      22.898     22.413
2        60        22.769        22.902     22.957      22.907     -0.187
3       120         22.78        22.895     25.519      22.911     -2.739
4       180        22.794        22.956      33.62      22.918    -10.827
```

short thing about what I try to do and where the problem is. I have this csv file, where there is a alot of data in it, with temperature readings every 60 seconds, for like 1400 readings. Now I want to interpolate that, so I can get a specific data point between each 60 seconds and possible even further than the 1400 iterations. (maybe up to 1600)
The first dataset I want, is the third celsius one. The code above is how far I got so far. Now I get the error code

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_8008/3128405253.py in <module>
      7 
      8 
----> 9 f = interpolate.interp1d(x, y, kind = 'cubic')
     10 yn =270  # Wert auf den Interpoliert werden soll
     11 t_on = f(yn)

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\interpolate.py in __init__(self, x, y, kind, axis, copy, bounds_error, fill_value, assume_sorted)
    434                  assume_sorted=False):
    435         """ Initialize a 1-D linear interpolation class."""
--> 436         _Interpolator1D.__init__(self, x, y, axis=axis)
    437 
    438         self.bounds_error = bounds_error  # used by fill_value setter

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\polyint.py in __init__(self, xi, yi, axis)
     52         self.dtype = None
     53         if yi is not None:
---> 54             self._set_yi(yi, xi=xi, axis=axis)
     55 
     56     def __call__(self, x):

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\polyint.py in _set_yi(self, yi, xi, axis)
    122             shape = (1,)
    123         if xi is not None and shape[axis] != len(xi):
--> 124             raise ValueError("x and y arrays must be equal in length along "
    125                              "interpolation axis.")
    126 

ValueError: x and y arrays must be equal in length along interpolation axis.
```

I searched for solutions and got this for example:

```
x = np.linspace(0, 4, 13)
y = np.linspace(0, 4, 13)  
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)  
z = np.arccos(-np.cos(2*X) * np.cos(2*Y))
f = interpolate.interp2d(x, y, z, kind = 'cubic')
```

I read at other problems, that the 2d solution should help, but when I put it like this I get:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_8008/1890924245.py in <module>
     14 f = interpolate.interp2d(x, y, z, kind = 'cubic')
     15 yn =270  # Wert auf den Interpoliert werden soll
---> 16 t_on = f(yn)
     17 print(t_on)
     18 

TypeError: __call__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'
```

Now I get it, I need something for y, but wouldnt that ruin the whole thing I try to do? My result should be my y and not one of my inputs.
If anyone can help me with my code or even has completely different other solution, I appreciate everthing. Thank you all for the help

Edit: the whole error message

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide the whole error message associated with `__call__() missing ...", as it likely contains critical information for solving this problem. Error messages usually start with "Traceback:"

Comment: Thank you for the comment! That was my bad. Thought that would be enough.
I edited the post, because I couldnt get the format to work here in the comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is here:

```
x = dataset.iloc[0:1420, 0:1].values
y = dataset.iloc[0:1420, 3:4].values
```

The result of a `0:1` slice will be a `DataFrame`, and you will end up with a two-dimensional array with the shape (1420, 1).
You need a 1d array for `interp1d`, so you should just do

```
x = dataset.iloc[0:1420, 0].values
y = dataset.iloc[0:1420, 3].values
```

The shape of `x` and `y` will be `(1420,)` (1d array).

Comment: This solved the issues with the equal length error! Thank you.
I had the error 'could not convert string to float', but that was because the array was from 0, which was an 's' and 'celsius'. so it had to be 1:1420
Would have loved to upvote your answer, but im restricted, because I need at least 15 reputation

Comment: Only thing im struggling again is this one 'TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe'''
I get this for the interpolate function ... Feels like an never ending story lol
If you have an idea and its not too much to help me once more, I would really appreciate it}

EDIT: cant believe, I think I got it. If maybe someone else needs this as an answer, my problem was

`xns = np.array(x, dtype=float)
yns = np.array(y, dtype=float)`

was needed. then xns and yns in interp1d

Comment: try to play with `pd.read_csv` parameters like `header` and `skip_rows`. pandas will infer you data type as float64 if there are no strings in the data.

Comment: btw, you can accept an answer if it solves your problem)

Comment: Didn't know that I can accept answers, thank you. Will also try different parameters! Thanks for all the help